# How can I add the unallocated head partition to the tail of the preceding partition on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

The whole situation is like this , recently I was using the Kali Linux along with Ubuntu as dual booted OS , due the some reasons Kali got broken packages and was not booting at all , then I was left with no option but to delete the Kali Linux, for the I booted in Ubuntu and deleted the partition on which Kali was. Now **I have unallocated space which I want to add in my   existing Ubuntu partition** . I am attaching the images of my configuration the right partition is the Ubuntu partition which I want to have extended.

[image: the right partition is the Ubuntu partition which i want to have extended]

Comment: sda4 is the Ubuntu partition?  If so, you can't do that.  The unallocated space needs to follow the partition you want to expand.  But do you really need more space in the Ubuntu partition?  You might be better off moving the Ubuntu contents to a new partition in the unallocated space (which will still be pretty huge), then make better use of the space in the current Ubuntu partition.  BTW, with as much free space as you have, consider doing things like splitting /Home to a separate partition, which will simplify backups and upgrades.  (cont'd)

Comment: Even if you have a ton of software, something on the order of 30 GB is usually plenty for a root partition.  That would leave 200 GB for a Home partition, which would handle good size collections of files.  You don't have a backup partition (actually better on a different drive if you have one), but if you can devote maybe 100 GB to something like Timeshift, that will give you the resources to recover from problems.

Comment: You could use GParted to simply move **sda3** and **sda4** to the "left", and that would create the unallocated area at the end of **sda4**.  But that is going to be a lengthy (and risky) operation, possibly 10 or more hours.  There is a faster and safer way, but you would need another storage drive of about 500GB (and a LiveCD to boot from).

Answer (score 0):

Either create a partition and mounted it at a point where that might be useful or you will need to move every partition. In most cases this is considered a dangerous operation so create a backup beforehand. There are various tools to do this.

For mounting check [mount man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) and [mkfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs). You will have to have a filesystem before you can use the space and can use it in several locations within your system. E.g you could use to as a mount point for `/home/<user>/mycollection` to store your collection of whatever that's currently taking up space on your root.

Alternatively use the tool you already got open (gparted) to move every partition to the start of the disk. See [gparted documentation](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions). Afterwards expand your partition. This is dangerous (create a backup) and you might need to use a [live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD). You might be unable to move the partition you're currently using.